# PHP start_session() error

Tags: php

**Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.**

I am getting this error while accessing the database. and in my project session is getting cleared automatically and i could not able to connect to server through filezilla .can you tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: yes i can tell you, if you show me the code

Comment: i did't get, can you tell me which file to show

Comment: show the code where you are trying to open a db connection or where u start your session, you probably have an error there

Comment: its happening on server,and i could not able to connect to server also how can i get the code from the server

Comment: is this because of write permission of tmp file

Comment: If you cannot connect to the server it sounds like you have a server issue have you contacted your host?

Comment: no show your php code, from the file that connect to the database.ex: mysql_connect(...) the file that contains that

Comment: $hostname_link = "localhost";
$database_link = "WebMain";
$username_link = "root";
$password_link = "";
$link = mysql_pconnect($hostname_link, $username_link, $password_link) or trigger_error("Unable to connect to the database!",E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_link, $link);

Comment: i got a solution that editing this file vi /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/etc/phpmyadmin/php.ini could solves the problem.any how i have to connect to server through shell prompt in putty.do you think will this solves the problem

Comment: oK, I contacted the host, the problem is with them only ,thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Please set error_reporting to `E_ALL` and `display errors` set to On. You will see some PHP error messages logged when you get this message.

It might be that IIS doesn't have write permissions to your temp directory where the sessions are stored.